# How to create cost maps based on OSM (landuse/...)?

Tags: qgis, postgis, openstreetmap, cost-path

I'd like to create cost maps (georef raster) for cross-country hiking based on OSM from pgsql/postgis plus height data.
Maybe by creating multiple raster-files and the later merging them (lake=unpassable, brige/ferry will later overwrite with a path).

Can someone please guide me to helpful threads or a "howto" for creating georef raster from psql/postgis OSM data without use of a tileserver.

Would gdal_rasterize be the right approach, or is there a better/faster way ?

Comment: What is a "georef raster", and what does serving tiles have to do with this? OSM data can be obtained as vectors.

Comment: Tiles:
my plan is not to setup a map-/tileserver, what some might suggest.
Georef:
came acros a lot threads with not geo-referrenced PNG output
OSM:
I would like to directly create raster files from the OSM-PostGIS data

Comment: As Example for a map snippet:

I don't wanna go for the 'routed' OSM network data, but creat a least cost path, crossing meadows and forests bee line.

![valid XHTML][checkmark] https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B6YLsIk_qHo_RjFLQ19QbVNselE [checkmark]

Comment: Edit the question to clarify instead of responding in comments.